# How to update multiple rows with SET CASE WHEN THEN with Doctrine query

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I have the following code, which generates DQL queries. 
When I echo my $dql and copy paste it into phpmyadmin and execute it, it works perfectly, but when trying to execute it with Doctrine I keep running into "***'[Syntax Error] line 0, col 6981: Error: Unexpected 'WHERE'***" error. What am I doing wrong?

```
$dqlStaticPartial = $dql = "UPDATE \VendorName\MyBundle\Entity\Product cp SET cp.guide_number = CASE ";
$uniqueIds = [];
$i = 0;

foreach($result as $row){
    $guideNumber = $this->generateGuideNumber($param1, $param2);
    $dql .= "WHEN cp.uniqid = '".$row['uniqid']."' THEN '$guideNumber' ";
    $uniqueIds[] = "'".$row['uniqid']."'";
    $i++;

    if($i % 100 === 0){
        $dql .= " END WHERE uniqid IN (".implode(',', $uniqueIds).")";
        $this->entityManager->createQuery($dql)->execute();
        $dql = $dqlStaticPartial;
    }
}
```

(I know, this is not okay, i'm going to put this in a transaction and I will execute the query after every 100th iteration and I'm gonna escape inputs etc...first I want my query to work)

Comment: Did you take a look at the contents of `$dql` ?

Comment: @Peter M Yes I did, I couldn't find any mistakes...but to be honest I've never wrote this kind of query in DQL so maybe even if  there are some mistakes in my DQL, I won't recognize them... If I run the content of the $dql in phpmyadmin, it works fine (If I change the fully qualified entity class name to the name of the table of course)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have more then 100 records and if that is the case then one of the problems you're creating is that your query ends up like this:

```
UPDATE cp SET cp.guide_number = CASE 
    WHEN cp.uniqid = '1' THEN '1234'
    -- more rows ...
    WHEN cp.uniqid = '99' THEN '4563'
    END
WHERE uniqid IN (1,...,99)
    WHEN cp.uniqid = '100' THEN '1234'
    -- more rows ...
    WHEN cp.uniqid = '199' THEN '4563'
    END
WHERE uniqid IN (100,...,199)
```

etc. etc.

You should clear the allready executed part of your query and then restart building up your query once you reach `($i % 100 === 0)`